# android edittext keyboard not showing after dialog dismissal

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, focus

I have an edit text that is working fine but after dismissing a dialog the keyboard is not showing despite the edit text is focused and the cursor is shown

I searched a lot and tried many solutions that didn't fix my issue

i tried these methods but they didn't work

```
public void showKeyboard(){
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}

public void closeKeyboard(){
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
}
```

and also tried adding them inside a runnable

Comment: Can you post the code you're using related to closing the dialog and using the EditText?

Comment: Please show your code for your AlertDialog box.

Comment: @cpgreen2 and @Beverly Castillo
the dialog is custom and extends AppCompatDialog in its constructor 

```
        if (this.getWindow() != null) {
            this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            this.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }
```
and it contains a cancel button to dismiss
```
cancelButton.setOnClickListener(view -> dismiss());
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the method I use to show keyboard for an edittext.

**kotlin code:**

below is an extension function for kotlin just need to call `edittext.showKeyboard()`

```
fun EditText.showKeyboard() {
  post {
    requestFocus()
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
  }
}
```

**the java code:**

```java
public static void showKeyboard(EditText editText) {
    editText.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        editText.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) editText.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
      }
    });
  }
```